# Angular 5 Datatables pop up a warning alert when re render

Tags: html, typescript, angular5, angular-datatables

I had succeed on creating a table and implement datatable on my angular 5 project

html code for the table:

```
<table class="table table-hover mt-3" datatable  [dtOptions]="dtOptionsContent" [dtTrigger]="dtTriggerContent">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Content Type</th>
            <th scope="col">User Occupation</th>
            <th scope="col">Content Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Carrot</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>           
        <tr *ngFor="let reward of rewards" >
            <td  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seeDetail" (click)="onSelect(reward)">{{getRewardType(reward.type)}}</td>
            <td  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seeDetail" (click)="onSelect(reward)">{{getRoleType(reward.role)}}</td>
            <td  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seeDetail" (click)="onSelect(reward)">{{reward.name}}</td>
            <td  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seeDetail" (click)="onSelect(reward)">{{reward.carrot}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

.ts code for the datatable settings:

```
dtOptionsContent: DataTables.Settings = {};
dtTriggerContent: Subject<any> = new Subject();

@ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
dtElementContent: DataTableDirective;
```

.ts for get rewards:

```
getRewards(): void 
{
    this.adminService.getRewards().subscribe(rewards=> {
        this.rewards = rewards;
        this.dtTriggerContent.next();
    });
}
```

The sorting, pagination, and searching are functional and when i add/delete a content to the table , the table is updated.

However, after updated, when i tried the sorting and pagination, the table content revert to the pre-added/deleted list.

I've tried destroy and rerender the table. This is the .ts code for adding content:

```
addSocial(role: number, rewardName: string, carrot: number): void 
{
    this.dtElementContent.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        let currentCarrot = 0;
        if(!isNaN(carrot))
        {
            //Setting for rewardTemp goes here

            this.adminService.addReward(this.rewardTemp)
            .subscribe(reward => {
                dtInstance.destroy();
                this.rewards.push(reward);
                this.dtTriggerContent.next();
            });

            //Success Notification goes here
        }
        else
            //Error Notification goes here
    });
}
```

while it succeed to sorting the updated content after the list was updated, it spawn warning alert after rerender.

The alert contains "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"

What is wrong??

Comment: Oh i should mention that i use multiple tables, if that helps